# Mouse Button 3 will no longer activate spaces in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Mouse Button 3 will no longer activate spaces in Snow Leopard.

Any ideas on how to get this working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer about Exposé not working from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/31597/logitech-g5-2007-edition-with-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-5th-button-not-invoking-expo):

*I am using the Logitech Control Center, but I also found that setting buttons to Spaces or Expose didn't work. Instead, I assigned the buttons to the function key which called those commands and it has been working find since.*

The solution that was accepted was to delete the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist file.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the plist doesn't work after a reboot.

Comment: I removed the middle button assignment from the logitech control panel and it started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System preferences -> Mouse-> Enable your secondary mouse button key to spaces and you are wellset to go.
(You should have enabled spaces also in spaces setting in system prefenrences.)